# How to distribute macros throughout they day when doing HIIT?

Tags: cardio, hiit

I'm doing insanity workout (I've done it several times before, 6-7 if I recall correctly), but this time I would like to do it more efficiently. I'm 181cm and 90kg (198 pounds) individual.

The amount of calories that I'm going to intake is 2200 kcal (lowering it each week), 2g proteins/kg = 180g (720 kcal), 1g fat/kg = 90g (810 kcal) and rest in carbs 167.5g (670 kcal).

I'm looking for a best way to distribute these macros throughout the day for the best effect. Also I want to try to keep my insuline level pretty stabilized so I'm only going to eat complex carbs without any spikes.

Idea was to have them distributed like this:

- breakfast = proteins + fats (eggs, avocado, cheese...)
- lunch = proteins + fats (chicken breasts, olives, tuna...)
- preworkout meal = proteins + carbs (oat meal + whey, whole wheat chicken breast sandwich...)
- shake = 30g of whey
- dinner = proteins + carbs (whole wheat pasta with cottage cheese...)

If going this route I will have to intake 160g of carbs in two meals. Is it better to offload part of carbs to the lunch (lets say 40g) or keep it this way?

Comment: It should be noted that unless you are a competing athlete or are experiencing undesirable energy levels during your workouts, it's really not too important. The ideal range for protein each meal is between 20-40 grams though. Reference here, http://www.nutritiontactics.com/measure-muscle-protein-synthesis/